# Is it safe to call Context.openFileOutput() from a non-UI thread?

Tags: android

I have a background task that opens a file and writes to it.  The task is initialized with a Context which is an activity.  The Context is then used to openFileOutput() in task's doInBackground().  Is this safe?

Comment: With Activity Context you might create a memory leak. Please post your code for a more detailed analysis.

Comment: You can use weak reference to `Context` as a class member of your AsyncTask and then get `Context` in `doInBackground` from this weak reference if it is not null.

Comment: Christopher: If I can guarantee that the task will exist only for as long as the activity that created it, do I still need to worry about a memory leak?